# Ansible | Making a retrying task run asynchronously on multiple servers

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a task that runs and retries a shell command until a certain string is not in the last line of the log file. It retries 500 times every second.

When the condition is met it shuts down the server. This works great when run one server at a time with `serial: 1`.

However I'd like to run this on multiple servers at once. The problem is it will wait for all servers to meet the condition before it shuts down all of them.

I'd like it to run asynchronously and shutdown each server as that server meets the condition.

I've tried `async: true` and `poll: 0` but that doesn't seem to work when `retry: true` is used in the task.

Here's a code snippet to give you an idea of what I'm doing.

```
- name: "Checking for inactivity on the server before shutdown"
  shell: "tail -1 serverlogs.log | egrep 'STRING1|STRING2' ||:"
  args:
    chdir: "/path/to/log/"
  register: check_inactivity
  until: '"STRING1" not in check_inactivity.stdout and "STRING2" not in check_inactivity.stdout'
  retries: 500
  delay: 1



- name: Debug message
  debug:
    msg: "Shutting down the server | {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: 'check_inactivity | changed'
```

This is what I'd like to achieve

```
- name: "Checking for inactivity on the server before shutdown"
  shell: "tail -1 serverlogs.log | egrep 'STRING1|STRING2' ||:"
  args:
    chdir: "/path/to/log/"
  register: check_inactivity
  until: '"STRING1" not in check_inactivity.stdout and "STRING2" not in check_inactivity.stdout'
  retries: 500
  delay: 1
  async: 45
  poll: 0


- name: Debug message
  debug:
    msg: "Shutting down the server | {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: 'check_inactivity | changed'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [strategy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html) to `free`:

```
- hosts: all
  strategy: free
  tasks:
    ...
```

This will instruct Ansible to run the tasks on each host as fast as possible, without waiting for the other hosts in a set.

Comment: Thank you. This works as desired!